# Regex for matching a sequence of incrementing numbers wihtin a given string of numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, match, matching

I have a javascript regex that matches an incrementing numerical value using look ahead however, I feel this can be simplified.

I currently am using `/^(?=[1-5]{5}$)(?=(?=.*([1]))(?=.*([2]))(?=.*([3]))(?=.*([4]))|(?=.*([2]))(?=.*([3]))(?=.*([4]))(?=.*([5])))\d+$/gm` to identify if at least 4 digits in a 5 digit string have values that increment by 1.

**Rules:**

- Can only contain numbers **1-5** and there must only be **5** characters in the string = `(?=[1-5]{5}$)`
- 4 of the 5 numbers ***must*** increment by 1, *they do not have to be grouped together*.
- Here I have entered 4 literal groups for each potential incrementing 4 digit string

  - `(?=.*([1]))(?=.*([2]))(?=.*([3]))(?=.*([4]))` and `(?=.*([2]))(?=.*([3]))(?=.*([4]))(?=.*([5]))`.
  - These are inside a look ahead with an `or` separator =>
    `(?=(?=.*([1]))(?=.*([2]))(?=.*([3]))(?=.*([4]))|(?=.*([2]))(?=.*([3]))(?=.*([4]))(?=.*([5])))\d+$`

Here is an example of strings that match the regex:

`12343` - 4 numbers increment in order starting at the 1

`32142` - 4 numbers increment, but not in order starting with the 1

`23451` - 4 numbers increment in order starting at the 2

`52345` - 4 numbers increment in order starting at the 2

`34152` - 4 numbers increment out of order, here we have 2 matches that are not in order, only one match is required

`12345` - 4 numbers increment in order, here we have 2 matches that are both in order, only one match is required

My regex seems to work with my tests, however I just feel there is a more dynamic and cleaner approach to this that I am just not privy to as my regex skills are below par to say the least.

Comment: This is doable with a regular expression, but only with one that has been repeatedly whooped with an ugly stick. You would need a start-of-string anchor followed by an alternation within a non-capture group, followed by `.*{5}$`. The alternation would have one part for each group of digits: 1-5, 2-6, 3-7, 4-8, 5-9, and with each part you would need 5 positive lookaheads, such as `(?=.*3)`...

Comment: ...By contrast that is pretty easy to do in code: 1) confirm the string contains five digits with no duplicates; 2) sort; 3) confirm the difference between the last and first digit (after converting to integers) equals 4.